# Was Freddie Mercury's voice range over 4 octaves?

Tags: history, queen

I was going through [some articles](https://www.quora.com/How-many-singers-have-or-have-had-a-five-5-octave-or-greater-voice-range) which listed Freddie's voice under the `Over 4 octaves` list.

But, haven't found an expert-backed opinion on the same.

So, **is Freddie's range really over 4 octaves?**

Comment: That's a pretty limited list! The one that immediately came to my mind is [Ivan Rebroff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Rebroff) (my father enjoyed his music, and I remember the LPs from my distant childhood!). FWIW.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Apparently it's not](http://www.people.com/article/freddie-mercury-voice-scientific-analysis):

> the late singer's inimitable voice was the subject of [a study by a
>   team of Austrian, Czech and Swedish authors](http://www.alphagalileo.org/ViewItem.aspx?ItemId=163213&CultureCode=en) who set out to analyze
>   Mercury's voice from archived recordings to figure out exactly what
>   made it so memorable.
>
> What did they discover? Well, first of all, **they cast doubt on a
>   commonly-recited fact: that Mercury had a four-octave singing voice**.
>   "This could not be substantiated by the study," the abstract reads,
>   with Austrian voice scientist Christian Herbst declaring that
>   **Mercury's voice range was "normal for a healthy adult – not more not
>   less."** The late singer was "probably a baritone who sang as a tenor,"
>   meaning his beautiful upper register and fluttering falsetto were the
>   result of exceptional control over what singers call their "head" and
>   "chest" voices and his ability to blend them.

Comment: Fabulous study - well found. My usable range in my youth [up to my late 30s even] was E2 - A#5, all in full voice, no falsetto... I never realised that was better than Freddie's [not that I would claim to have ever sounded as good, but I did spend a great deal of my time in the 80s as a studio session singer doing 'Queen-style' block vocals for other bands  ;) Of course, it's fairly well-known that Roger Taylor did a lot of the higher lines.

Comment: This is an interesting video of Brian May explaining Bohemian Rhapsody: https://youtu.be/4gn81lb7twI He mentions that most vocals are multiple tracks of Freddy plus additional backing vocals from all three, but the very end of the operatic part "for me, for me, for MEEEEEEEE" is Roger alone, because he was the only one capable of hitting the note.

Comment: Ah, I misremembered: https://youtu.be/4gn81lb7twI?t=18m31s Close enough.